# Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 3, 4

Tags: r, json, dataframe, plot, corpus

I'm trying to create a data frame from a json file.

I tried the following code:
> head(names(data_jstor))

```
[1] "creator" "datePublished" "docType" "fullText"
[5] "id" "identifier"

> names(data_jstor)

[1] "creator" "datePublished" "docType" "fullText"
[5] "id" "identifier" "isPartOf" "issueNumber"
[9] "language" "outputFormat" "pageCount" "pageEnd"
[13] "pageStart" "pagination" "provider" "publicationYear" [17] "publisher" "sourceCategory" "tdmCategory" "title"
[21] "url" "volumeNumber" "wordCount" "unigramCount"
[25] "bigramCount" "trigramCount"
    > head(na.action(data_jstor))
NULL
> str(data_jstor)

List of 26 $ creator : chr "Fred. Perry Powers" $ datePublished : chr "1900-08-01" $ docType : chr "article" $ fullText : chr [1:8] "552 QUARTERLY JOURNAL OF ECONOMICS THE STOCK OF GOLD IN THE COUNTRY. The amount of gold in the country, as comp"| truncated "NOTES AND MEMORANDA 553 If we eliminate the state banks, we find that the percent- ages of gold and of legal te"| truncated "554 QUARTERLY JOURNAL OF ECONOMICS three years the percentage which each kind of money consti- tuted in the tot"| truncated "NOTES AND MEMORANDA 555 Treasury stated to be in the hands of the people, and the per- centages deposited in 5,"| truncated ... $ id : chr "http://www.jstor.org/stable/1883426" $ identifier :List of 5 ..$ :List of 2

data_jstor_df<-as.data.frame(data_jstor)
```

But I have a error message:Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 3, 4

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe if you could show the output of your `str(data_jstor)` or at least part of `data_jsor`, we can help you.

Comment: I couldn't fix it, I was just putting the str (data_jstor), so you could have more clarity about data_jstor